# Generic method to return Dictionary for all its property

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I want to write a generic method, which accept a class object of any type and return a keyValuepair for all the properties of that object.

```
public Dictionary<string,string> GetProperties(T classObj)
{
}
```

Any help on this would be very greatful.

Comment: Have you looked at using reflection?

Comment: Try to get all the properties by reflection. In this case what will be your key in the dictionary, hope you have planned to use propertyNames. Take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020041/reflection-class-to-get-all-properties-of-any-object

Comment: Try Reflection , check this (possible duplication) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762531/c-sharp-reflection-and-getting-properties

Answer (score 2):

Using reflection:

```
public Dictionary<string, object> GetProperties<T>(T classObj)
{
    return typeof(T).GetProperties()
            .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.GetValue(classObj, null));
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use Generics here - `object classObj` is sufficient. Also, using `typeof(T)` you could miss out on properties if you supplied `GetProperties<BaseClass>` but passed an object which extended `BaseClass` so use `classObj.GetType()` instead.